# no sound in MIT scratch after upgrade to 22.10

Tags: upgrade, sound, 22.10

MIT scratch is a great for teaching kids to program. It has been working for a couple of years on my computers. Since upgrading from 22.04 to 22.10 there seems to be a bug that there is no sound. We discovered it when trying to record a sound and heard nothing. Then when using predefined sounds (cat meow etc, etc) there was also no sound.

I tried it on a second computer, also recently upgraded to 22.10 and the problems appears here too. Can anyone try to duplicate the problem to see if I am missing something? I could well be that something in scratch is too system dependent and the problem is there. Clearly I hear sound under most programs, so I might need to contact MIT.

This is Scratch 1.4 (Linux) of 2-Dec-11. It is from https://scratch.mit.edu/scratch_1.4.

Comment: I've noticed in the log `sound: /dev/dsp: No such file or directory` appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing osspd (by running `sudo apt install osspd`) and rebooting fixed the issue for me. However, Scratch does crash quite often. At least it also fixes fullscreen.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me as well.

Comment: You're welcome! It's a shame the recoding function still has issues though.

Comment: I just checked making a recording. It seems to be working here. I can see that some of the prerecorded sounds, e.g. instruments - Dijjeridoo, make no sound.

Comment: Using Wine appears to work better.

Answer (score 0):

Scratch-1.4 is an 11 year old program. The Git source to it has been archived and closed. Since the sound is closely connected to the underlying hardware, it is not surprising that Ubuntu apparently dropped support for an old sound system.

A quote from their wiki says: The Scratch 2.0 Offline editor could be downloaded for Windows, Mac and Linux directly from Scratch's website, although support for Linux was later dropped.

There are 2 possible solutions:

1 use virtual box to run Windows and run Scratch 3 inside the virtual  box.

2 run scratch on line using https://scratch.mit.edu/ which means that scratch runs in a browser and is operating system independent.

Comment: You can also use https://flathub.org/apps/details/edu.mit.Scratch for the offline Scratch 3 editor.